# How can I use HTML code to print it in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use this HTML code and print it in PHP.

In the HTML code I use this:

`<button onMouseover="htmlcode('<img src=\'http://www.chinavalue.net/Special/images/20080529/image/top.jpg\'></img>');">View</button>`

How should it be used it in PHP?

I've tried this code:

```
 echo '<button onMouseover="htmlcode('<img src=\'http://www.chinavalue.net/Special/images/20080529/image/$test.jpg\'></img>');">View</button>';
```

But unfortunately, this is not working.

Comment: Start by learning basic PHP syntax: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.string.php  ignore the fact that you're outputting html/javascript. It's just a string as far as PHP is concerned, and that means you have to follow PHP's string syntax rules.

Comment: May I recommend the PHP course at http://codecademy.com?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: No, you may not. They are no better than W3Schools.

Comment: How so @TheBlueDog? We have seen anecdotally that they teach the basics pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

you mix up your quotes

if you use ' quotes in the echo statement, you cannot use them (or have to escape them) in the string

the best solution here is escape the single quotes in your string, so they don't mark the end of the echo command

```
 echo('<button onMouseover="htmlcode(\'<img src=\'http://www.chinavalue.net/Special/images/20080529/image/top.jpg\'></img>\');">View</button>');
```

Comment: In this case `htmlcode'<img src='` <- you will get JS error here. Think it over.

Comment: yeah you are right, then the best solution would probably be to just pass in the image src to the htmlcode function and then concat it together in js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in some kind of an `if statement` then you can go for this:

```
<?php if( /*your condition*/ ) :?>
    <button onMouseover="htmlcode('<img src=\'http://www.chinavalue.net/Special/images/20080529/image/top.jpg\'> </img>');">View</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note this way you can write long snippets of html easily, which is not the case with `echo`.

If this is not conditional, then just do something like this:

```
<?php // some php code
// some more php
?>
<html>
    Your html here
</html>
<?php // next section of php
// more php
?>
```

The parts between the php sections will be outputed just as if they were put into an `echo` statement.

Comment: i dont want to use that       in the code there is $

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the html in the browser then you can use.

```
print htmlspecialchars("<button onMouseover="htmlcode('<img src=\'http://www.chinavalue.net/Special/images/20080529/image/top.jpg\'></img>');">View</button>")
```